# How to run javascript image slideshow via external js file?

Tags: javascript

i have this slider on my website ans is working fine ... it is just and image changer which changes the images on the slide show and its code is written in the main.html file is this

```
<img src="images/1.jpg" name="slide"  width="100%" height="368" />
<script>
<!--
    var image1=new Image()
    image1.src="images/1.jpg"
    var image2=new Image()
    image2.src="images/4.jpg"
    var image3=new Image()
    image3.src="images/3.jpg"

    //variable that will increment through the images
    var step=1
    function slideit(){
        //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
        if (!document.images)
            return
        document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
        if (step<3)
            step++
        else
            step=1
        //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
        setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
    }
    slideit()
//-->
</script>
```

now its working absolutely fine.. all what i want is that i have a file name page1.js i want to put my javascript code in that file instead of my main.html file.. please tell me how i put this javascript code in that page1.js file and call it so that the image slide show will work fine as it is working now having the javascript code in the same file..

Answer (score 1):

Put your javascript from above into a file named `my-slides.js`, and then replace the script tag in your current HTML file with this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-slides.js"></script>
```

Ensure that `my-slides.js` is in the same folder as your HTML file, otherwise change the path accordingly.

---

FWIW, although you have not asked for this in your question, I think I should also mention the following:

- Consider using curly braces to define code blocks in `if` and `else` blocks, even when it is a single line. Really improves code readability
- This line: `document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")` uses `eval` and you should avoid it. I am not sure what is accomplished here by wrapping your string concatenation with an eval. I would store the `Image`s in an array and access this by index instead.
- Rather than have a `setTimeout` within the function to recur, consider using `setInterval` outside of the function.

---

As requested.

This is what `my-slides.js` should contain.

```
    var numImages = 3;
    var images = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numImages; ++i) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = 'images/' + (i + 1) + '.jpg';
        images.push(image);
    }

    var step = 0;
    function slideit() {
        if (! document.images) {
            return;
        }
        document.images.slide.src = images[step].src;
        step = (step + 1) % numImages;
    }
    setInterval(slideit, 2500);
```

Comment: its not working yet:-( can you please tell me the exact code to be written in "my-slides.js"  remember this my-slides.js file is placed on main.html file is .. so no issue of image path i guess

Comment: @ArslanTariq I've appended this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is include your JS file either at your footer or header :

```
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

and then in that JS file wil contain :

```
        var image1=new Image()
     image1.src="images/1.jpg"
     var image2=new Image()
     image2.src="images/4.jpg"
   var image3=new Image()
   image3.src="images/3.jpg"

   //variable that will increment through the images
       var step=1
       function slideit(){
 //if browser does not support the image object, exit.
  if (!document.images)
  return
  document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
  if (step<3)
  step++
  else
  step=1
  //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
  setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
  }
  slideit()
```

the only thing you need to change is the path for the images themselves, they can be either relative to the JS file or absolute.